# NDSolve not giving result

Tags: differential-equations

The system of ODE is not giving an output.

```
NDSolve[{x'[t] ==\alpha_1 -\alpha_2*x[t]*z[t] + \alpha_3*y[t] - \alpha_4*x[t],\\
  y'[t] == \alpha_2*x[t]*z[t] - \alpha_3*y[t] - \alpha_4*y[t],\\
  z'[t] == \alpha_4*y[t] - \alpha_5*z[t], x[0] == 10, y[0] == 5, z[0] == 5}\\,{x,y,z},{t,0,150}]
```

Its expected to be written as seen in the image
[image]

Comment: `α` is written `\[Alpha]`

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks

Comment: Just search alpha and Subscript in the document by pressing **F1**, you can easily find the way to input them. (Online document is here BTW: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/InputAndOutputInNotebooks.html#14875 ) Getting used to reading the document is the first thing to learn when you start using _Mathematica_.

Answer (score 4):

Use `alpha1` instead of `alpha_1` etc.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
{alpha1, alpha2, alpha3, alpha4, alpha5} = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == 
     alpha1 - alpha2*x[t]*z[t] + alpha3*y[t] - alpha4*x[t], 
    y'[t] == alpha2*x[t]*z[t] - alpha3*y[t] - alpha4*y[t], 
    z'[t] == alpha4*y[t] - alpha5*z[t], x[0] == 10, y[0] == 5, 
    z[0] == 5}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 150}];
Plot[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. sol // Evaluate, {t, 0, 150}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The image inserted

Comment: @Grace I have answered your question,just add the values of all the unknown `alpha`.

Comment: Its clearer now

Answer (score 1):

A more general approach is as follows.

```
Clear["Global`*"];

psol = ParametricNDSolve[{x'[t] == 
 alpha1 - alpha2*x[t]*z[t] + alpha3*y[t] - alpha4*x[t], 
y'[t] == alpha2*x[t]*z[t] - alpha3*y[t] - alpha4*y[t], 
z'[t] == alpha4*y[t] - alpha5*z[t], x[0] == 10, y[0] == 5, 
z[0] == 5}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 150}, {alpha1, alpha2, alpha3, 
alpha4, alpha5}];
Plot[Evaluate[{x[1, 1, 1, 1, 1][t], y[1, 1, 1, 1, 1][t], 
z[1, 1, 1, 1, 1][t]} /. psol], {t, 0, 150}]
```

[image]